# Export DXF from QGIS; points' metadata as text element

Tags: qgis, convert, export, dxf

I have a layer (Esri shapefile) which has points in it. Each point has 'property identifier' as metadata. (Boundaries and boundary markers are in different layers / files.)

In QGIS I changed the appearance of layer so that 'property identifier' shows as a text, for example "148-405-1-101". This way: *Layer Properties* > *Style: Font marker* > *data override* with *Field type: string*, and picked up the right metadata field. This works fine.

Now I'm trying to export/save that layer as DXF, but in DXF points will be points, not text elements. Is there a way to convert points' data into text elements in DXF?

I tried via *Project* > *DXF Export...* and *Layer* > *Save as...*

I also found this: https://www.qgis.ch/en/projects/dxf-export. 
Could it be just encoding problem? Of which I don't know anything...

I'm not a GIS expert so I'm sorry if there's any clumsiness in my explanation.